# Sword Coast Legends Glitches with Radeon HD 6770 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, 15.10

Ubuntu newbie trying to play sword coast legends here. The first time, I got some glitches that made the game unplayable. I tried with proprietary drivers following this [italian guide](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/Video/Ati/CatalystDaTerminale) with no luck. The glitches are sticking around. Not to mention I've yet to find how to run it in fullscreen, but that's secondary. I have a Radeon HD 6770, ubuntu 15.10. This is what I get:

[Any greatsword becomes a massive mace in the hands of Belamy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO4UD.jpg)
[Daylight that would kill anything, not just vampires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ew4I.jpg)

You can also see the solid color dialog scenes here (color varies):

[image: img]

And this is what comes out of the `lspci` command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Juniper XT [Radeon HD 6770]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Juniper HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5700 Series]
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```